# How to register a rhino stub in MS unity?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-container, rhino-mocks

I'm using Ms `unity container` and `rhino mock` for creating stubs.

I try to create stub and register it in my unity container

```
IUnityContainer container = ContainerManager.GetDefaultContainer;

var loggerStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ILogger>();

container.RegisterType<ILogger, loggerStub>();
```

however, only class type can be registered.

How can I register stub (like logger stub) inorder to rn my unit-test?

Comment: Your unit tests should not rely on your IOC container.  Your IOC container (in production) will inject the required dependencies for your components.  At test time, you should be creating the components and handing them mocked/stubbed instances (via a mocking framework).

Comment: my class under test injects everything from the container. So i thought using the container for `handing them mocked/stubbed instances`. No?

Comment: Can you show an example of the code you want to test and what dependencies it needs -- and how it gets those dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also configure a Unity Container to resolve a given type to a specified instance, using [the RegisterInstance method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649971.aspx).

So, in your registration code you'll need to change the last line to:

```csharp
container.RegisterInstance(typeof(ILogger), loggerStub);
```

However, I find it a bit strange that you need to use an IoC container in your unis tests.

You should be able to manually create an instance of your system under test.

In my experience, I've used IoC in tests in the following cases:

- when I needed to test the container configuration itself (ex: see that a particular type can be successfully resolved)
- when I had so many dependencies that it wasn't easy to manually specify them (in such cases the problem was actually either bad design or poor test isolation)
- when I needed to perform integration tests (not unit tests)

#### Update

I saw your comment and I could immediately think of two reasons not to use injection in unit tests:

- You'd have to do more work than necessary. In the application you set up one container and it resolves everything. In the case of tests you'll need to set up many container configurations with different stubs/mocks (depending on what you are testing in each of the unit tests). I think it's easier to manually supply any dependencies to the classes under test.
- In some tests you may forget to set up stubs for all dependencies and your unit tests may end up access external resources (e.g. database, remote service).

Comment: Nothing wrong with using Unity in unit tests IMHO. This might be because: -
(a) You want to confirm that the DI is correctly set up if e.g. you are using Property Injection.
(b) You are using interception.

Comment: my class under test injects everything from the container. So i thought אם use the container for handing them mocked/stubbed instances. No?

Comment: @EladBenda In tests you should manually supply the dependencies for the class under test. In this case a container would be an additional level of indirection with no added benefit IMHO.

Comment: @IsaacAbraham Agreed. That's very close to the first bullet in my list.